# Any differences between these two ways of creating an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a tutorial for numpy, and it's creating an array using 'b' as below. Why doesn't it use 'a'? I tested and it seems both 'a' and 'b' have the same effect. Is that right?

```
 In [39]: a = np.random.normal(0, 1.5, (10))                                                                                                                   

In [40]: b = np.random.normal(0, 1.5, (10,))                                                                                                                  

In [41]: a.shape                                                                                                                                              
Out[41]: (10,)

In [42]: b.shape                                                                                                                                              
Out[42]: (10,)

In [43]: a                                                                                                                                                    
Out[43]: 
array([-0.10626252,  0.54973224, -0.9940606 ,  2.96486485, -2.41171607,
        3.59483954,  1.19982736,  0.66358172,  0.93966334, -0.99427335])

In [44]: b                                                                                                                                                    
Out[44]: 
array([-1.39136937,  0.38089925, -1.25003939,  3.27460748, -3.10624895,
       -1.27641556, -2.06235267, -0.50606768,  0.21605496, -0.4252462 ])
```

Comment: The different between `(10,)` and `(10)` (without the trailing comma inside the parens) is the first creates a 1 element tuple and the second doesn't -- it just evaluates what's inside (the integer 10).  In this case, numpy may handle the two different ways of specifying the third argument, but they're not the same in general.

Comment: The `normal` docs says `size` can be either a tuple or integer.  `(10)` is an integer; python ignores the ().  `(10,)` is a single element tuple.  Often when specifying `shape`, an integer is treated as though it were the tuple, since there's not ambiguity as to the users intent.  Look at the `shape` input for `np.zeros`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you defined both `a` and `b` are the same, however the random numbers will differ between the two. The structure of each one is the same, as well as the purpose (i.e. sample numbers from a normal distribution).

Comment: Yeah, of course, his saying to process of the two, one with trailing comma, one without.

Comment: I am wondering why the author doesn't use the simpler form: (0, 1.5, (10))

Comment: The shortest valid form is (0, 1,5, 10),  The extra () around 10 is a harmless mistake.  (10,) is the more precise usage.